# Unable to create a new column from a list using spark concat method?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, python-3.6, pyspark-schema

i have below data frame in which i am trying to create a new column by concatinating name from a list

```
df=

----------------------------------
| name| department|  state| id| hash
------+-----------+-------+---+----
James|  Sales1   |null   |101|4df2
Maria|  Finance  |       |102|5rfg
Jen  |           |NY2    |103|234

key_list=['name','state','id']

df.withColumn('prim_key', concat(*key_list)
df.show()
```

but above return the same result

```
----------------------------------
| name| department|  state| id| hash
------+-----------+-------+---+----
James|  Sales1   |null   |101|4df2
Maria|  Finance  |       |102|5rfg
Jen  |           |NY2    |103|234
```

i suspecting it might be due to space in the column names in DF. so i used trim to remove all space in column names, but no luck . it returning the same result

Any solution to this?

Comment: could be typo but did you assign the result of `withColumn` back to `df` (`df = df.withColumn()`)?

Comment: Hi @Emma yes.. i assigned as you mentioned.. i am wondering what could be the reason? i checked with another example of df locally without have any space in column name, and that works fine.. but in this case, these df are derived from a database..

Comment: did df.show() now display the expected result?

Comment: no as said its not creating new column 'prim_key' with concatination of those columns

Comment: could you try `df = df.withColumn('prim_key', lit(1))`  and `df.show()`?   do you see  `prim_key` column?  or do you see any errors?

Answer (score 0):

i found it... the issue was due to assigning the result to new or existing df

```
df=df.withColumn('prim_key', concat(*key_list)
```

Comment: thats right -- rdds are immutable, so you should assign modified rdd or you'd loose your changes.